# PL/SQL Trigger not detecting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Hi I am learning triggers at university and I am trying to implement a simple function to understand the logic. I am attempting to create a trigger that prohibits an employee to possess more than 4 projects simultaneously. 
All compiles correctly, however when I test the trigger by adding a 5th project to an employee, the trigger won't detect it. Would anyone be able to explain in my logic what I am doing incorrectly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MAXPROJECTS 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON WorksOn FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
project_count INT(10);

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(p#) INTO project_count
FROM WorksOn WHERE e# =:NEW.e#;

IF (project_count > 4) 
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 
'employee is already working on 4 
projects.');
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Because of `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma. Your trigger(select statement ) sees only committed data. You can make it work in the way you expect it to work if each `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement is a separate transaction (you need to commit after every single `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement) and IF condition is changed from `project_count > N` to `project_count > N - 1`. But I would advise against implementing this logic in triggers. Implement it in a stored procedure (API) instead

Comment: PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION = Start Bug Here.

Comment: By the way, this kind of business rule is notoriously hard to implement and triggers may not be the right approach. For one thing, what if the same employee gets assigned to five projects in five separate sessions at the same time? The trigger only sees other sessions' committed data.

Answer (score 1):

The `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` means your trigger will run in its own transaction. Since it's a separate transaction, it can't view the **uncommitted** data you just inserted, and thus does not fail the insert statement.

This pragma is primarily useful for "side effect" trigger (e.g., logging to another table), where you don't want a failure in the "side effect" to fail the entire action. In this usecase, you expect the exact opposite, and thus, should not use this pragma.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems here.

First, I'm going to guess that you tried to make this a ROW trigger without the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION and it blew up on you, so you searched StackOverflow and found out about using this PRAGMA to get around the "mutating table" exception - and that's still not doing it for you.

As far as being able to count the number of projects assigned to an employee, there are a couple different ways to accomplish your goal but the easiest is to make this a STATEMENT trigger instead of a ROW trigger, which is done by leaving out the `FOR EACH ROW` clause in the trigger definition. A statement trigger fires only once per statement instead of once for each row affected by the statement, and you don't have access to the :NEW or :OLD values - but if you think about it right you realize that you don't actually need those values.

Secondly, you'd made this a BEFORE trigger which fires before the statement has executed, so the changes which were to be made by the statement weren't visible in the trigger. So this needs to be an AFTER trigger.

The following should do what you're looking for

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER WORKSON_BIU_STMT
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON WorksOn
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT e#, COUNT(DISTINCT p#) AS PROJECT_COUNT
                 FROM WorksOn
                 GROUP BY e#)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('E#=' || aRow.E# || '  PROJECT_COUNT=' || aRow.PROJECT_COUNT);

    IF aRow.PROJECT_COUNT > 4 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'Employee ' || aRow.e# || ' cannot be assigned to ' || aRow.PROJECT_COUNT || ' projects.');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END WORKON_BIU_STMT;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4c5bc30d059c7f1c83a23f1ba970b81)

Comment: Bob Jarvis, Love you so much.